# Using left join for the same table or is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table called `bans` where I have the follow fields:

```
room_id, banned_user_id, banned_by_id, reason, ts_start, ts_end
```

The users data come from the table called `users`, now I wanted to query the bans to retrive the name of who was banned and by who along with reason, time the ban was placed and time it ends.

So I have this query:

```
SELECT u.username, us.username, b.reason, b.ts_start, b.ts_end
FROM `bans` b 
LEFT JOIN users us ON b.banned_by_uid = us.uid 
LEFT JOIN users u ON b.banned_uid = u.uid
WHERE room_id = 3
```

**My question here is wether my query is ok by using the LEFT JOIN for the 2 data I have to grab from the table `users` or there is a different approach for this kinda of scenario ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is perfectly acceptable. Each join to `users` is on a specific ID, which translates into a simple lookup, with minimal overhead.